# BannerViewController interferes with hidesBottomBarWhenPushed

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, iad

I'm implememting a design based on the TabbedBanner example in the iAdSuite. I have a UINavigationController in the first tab. In that UINavigationController I have a view controller that simply has a button that pushes to another view controller. The pushed view controller is set to Hide Bottom Bar On Push in Interface Builder.

Here is the code where I'm setting up the UITabBarController.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:[[NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary objectForKey:@"UIMainStoryboardFile"] bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    _tabBarController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarController"];
    _tabBarController.delegate = self;

    FirstViewController *firstView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstViewController"];
    UINavigationController *firstNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstView];

    _tabBarController.viewControllers = @[[[BannerViewController alloc] initWithContentViewController:firstNav], ];

    self.window.rootViewController = _tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Everything works except the TabBar does not get hidden when I push to the next view controller. I have tried hiding the TabBar using the Interface Builder check box as well as using nextViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES and neither way works.

If I remove the BannerViewController implementation, the TabBar hides exactly as it should.
It seems to me that the BannerViewController is interfering with the UINavigationController being able to hide the TabBar.

Is it possible to use Hides Bottom Bar When Pushed to hide the TabBar in this type of setup?

Thanks

Note: I realize that the code above only has one tab. I removed the other tabs for clarity.

Comment: How did you fix this?

Comment: I never did get it worked out. I'm really surprised that I never got a single answer on this question. I should take another look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is happening because the BannerViewController itself is just a container viewController and it never actually pushes another view controller. The view controllers are pushed within the container.